# Special treatment for LE family member?

Tags: california, police, professional-ethics

Is preferential treatment illegal? If LE can employ a judgement call into decision making, are there established limits?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about police praxis, not the law.

Comment: Understood. Any recommendations?

Comment: you could ask if it is illegal to show preferential treatment, you could ask what limits there are to treating one way or another, but  "is it done" only is good if you combine it with "is it legal"

Comment: I appreciate your clarity! Will rewrite as soon as I figure out how to.

Comment: try [edit] under the post

Comment: there's a *lot* of digression left to a police officer, especially when it comes to estimating the necessary force - and influence by a family member can be a factor in deciding if force is needed or not. What kind of preferential are we talking here? What kind of situation? Are we talking arrest or trespass? Give us like... 2 examples?

Comment: Okay... In both examples: involved parties are the same and frequent off-duty associations are commonly known to community.

Comment: 1. First court date for divorce, one party requests in retraining order financial restraint on commonly held investments,  a drug test OR supervised visits with children, and no in-person contact with spouse. Other party does not attend court date after being served appropriately and restraining order is denied 100% and person not attending is awarded 1/2 physical custody and is not requested to pay any child support.

Comment: 2. (Sorry, the "add comment"  button is too close for fat fingers).

Comment: Second example... Person not attending court is reported to LE as a thief and/or burglery suspect (this action is seperate from divorce). Witness to confession is willing to swear to facts and items stolen are shown to LE. LE removes all items stated to be stolen and later, upon inquiry, LE states insufficient evidence.

Comment: This *sounds* like misconduct by the LE, but it is always hard to judge a case just from one summary. Are those specific, real-world cases and are you somehow involved? Then you might need to talk to a lawyer.

Comment: There are things that need to be shown to get a restraining order. Insufficient evidence can mean a lot. or that you are not allowed to know.

Comment: O. M.... Sadly, very real world. Tiny smidge of a town where everyone knows everyone. I see your point regarding what my words make it seem like. I am involved, I am a key player,  I stand alone in this mess of several years now. It's clear I will likely continue losing where I never should have. I'd really like to know how others have dealt with similar situations.

Comment: Trish... True. I would love an RO. Not confident it would halt anything but it would help get that ball rolling. Frankly, these and another separate but equally indicative incident  involving protecting a brother, it leaves a person with little hope, and an absence of respect for some wearing a uniform.